# Solving date intervals intersections

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a table that holds

- color name
- number of a start of this color usage month and number of an end
- order of apperance in database

Creating a table:

```
create table colorTimes (iOrder int, color varchar(10), pStart int, pEnd int)
```

Now we got to input some colors data in it:

```
insert into colorTimes (iOrder, color, pStart, pEnd) values (1, 'green', 2, 12)
insert into colorTimes (iOrder, color, pStart, pEnd) values (2, 'blue', 4, 4)
insert into colorTimes (iOrder, color, pStart, pEnd) values (3, 'red', 9, 10)
insert into colorTimes (iOrder, color, pStart, pEnd) values (4, 'yellow', 6, 7)
insert into colorTimes (iOrder, color, pStart, pEnd) values (5, 'orange', 1, 2)
insert into colorTimes (iOrder, color, pStart, pEnd) values (6, 'violet', 7, 9)
```

The rule is that a color with a higher iOrder value is in higher priority and overlaps
lower priority color intervals by cutting them on a value that it needs to fit its own.
When a newer row lands in a center of more older row, it cutts it in two pieces.
So we need to perform some actions to get data in this table in right form - without intersections keeping up this rule. Graphically it looks like: [image]

Input:

[image]

Required output:

[image]

As you see in result, row that stands for a green line is cutted by others into three rows
and still valid on some time intervals.

This highly abstracted example hides a problem of interacting with data, stored like Value\DateBegin\DateEnd
partitions and intersections of it. 
The main goal is to get only one value that stands for a certain time (i.e. we need to know
which color is for 8th month):

```
select color from colorTimes where 8 between pStart and pEnd
```

[image]

By some circumstances we are unable to:

- Use cheeky triggers while inputing initial data.
- Change any logic of work with initial data, methods of picking it up by 
  the application (it uses same select every time and expects to see only one value).
- Change the way that data stores.

Comment: So you're wanting to make updates to the table to transform it into what you show in required output?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thx for the DML script.

Here's how I would do it (SQL Server 2012+):

```
;with x as (
    select *,
    row_number() over(partition by n order by iorder desc) as rn
    from colortimes c
    inner join numbers n on n.n between c.pstart and c.pend
),
y as (
    select distinct iOrder, color, n, 
        lead(color) over (order by n) as lead_color,
        isnull(lag(n) over(order by n), 0) + 1 as pend
    from x
    where rn = 1
),
z as (
    select *,       
        isnull(lag(n) over(order by n), 0) + 1 as pstart
    from y
    where color <> lead_color or lead_color is null
)
select iorder, color, pstart, pend
from z
--where 8 between pstart and pend
order by n
```

About the [numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/).

Comment: Sry for late answer, but it seems that you forgot to define table numbers?